# Using getClass in jar returning null point exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classloader, configurationmanager

I have attempted about everything I have seen regarding this issue on stackoverflow but can't seem to correctly retrieve an xml file using the .getClass method. I am continuing to get a null pointer exception but can't figure out why. I have tried several variations. If I am doing anything wrong please let me know. Also, if you require any additional information just ask :D. Here are some of the variations I have tried

```
URL configURL = new URL("" + Transcriber.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml"));
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(configURL);

URL configURL = new URL("" + Transcriber.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/config.xml"));
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(configURL);

InputStream configURL = Transcriber.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml");
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(configURL.toString());
```

I should also note that when using eclipse I am able to retrieve the xml. However, when converted to an executable jar I cannot.

EDIT:

```
URL configURL = new URL("" + Transcriber.class.getResourceAsStream("config.xml"));
```

Console output =

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: java.io.BufferedInputStream@238be9f2
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at speechcapture.Transcriber.main(Transcriber.java:53)
```

Comment: Where is the `config.xml`  resource in the jar?

Comment: It is located in the same package folder with Transcriber.class (bin/speechcapture/)

Comment: A previous post explains this problem perfectly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119740/loading-files-with-classloader

Comment: @AurA I seem to have attempted the approaches listed in the link unless I missed one when reading over the answers provided.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that

```
Transcriber.class.getClass()
```

returns the `Class` object for the `Class` class. What you wanted was

```
Transcriber.class
```

The second problem is that, assuming your `config.xml` resource is in the same package as the `Transcriber` class, then you need to either provide the fully qualified path to the resource or get it relative to the `Transcriber` class' package. So either

```
URL configURL = Transcriber.class.getResource("config.xml");
```

or

```
URL configURL = Transcriber.class.getResource("/com/example/config.xml");
```

Comment: I have tried URL configURL = new URL("" + Transcriber.class.getResourceAsStream("config.xml")); as well and config.xml is in the same package as the Transcriber class.

Comment: @user2916286 Both of the entries in my answer will work _if_ both the class `Transcriber` and the `config.xml` file are in the same package. Note how the `URL` is constructed.

Comment: I added it as written but I am still seeing the error null pointer exception. But with adding your's I am now seeing a malformed URL exception.

Comment: @user2916286 Post the exact one you're using and the full stack trace. Do this in an edit your question.

Comment: Just posted in question

Comment: @user2916286 Note the difference between my code and yours. Why are you constructing your `URL` like that?

Comment: I had tried both getResource then switched to getResourceAsStream.

Comment: @user2916286 if you're using `getResourceAsStream` why do you need a URL?

Comment: What would you recommend? I had tried InputStream as well. The issue is that while these will work in eclipse (like yours). It is giving me issues when turning it into jar.

Comment: @user2916286 You either use `getResourceAsStream` and get an `InputStream` or use `getResource` and get a `URL`. The way you were using it didn't make any sense. As for the Eclipse vs jar issue, make sure Eclipse is building the jar correctly with all the resources added where they should be.