# How to read a properties file in different Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I have two Java Projects, and I am trying to read the properties file in one from another. I have added "Infrastructure" Project in Build path of "Java" Project, and the properties file is at root folder, but I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException` I tried bunch ways, but couldn't make it work. Which part is causing the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("application.properties"));
}
```

Here is the Project Explorer;

[image]

Comment: Add a `resources/` folder under `src/` and load the properties file from the ClassLoader using `getResourceAsStream()`. See: [SO: Loading files with ClassLoader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119740/loading-files-with-classloader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `properties.load(YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"))` instead.